# Is there a legal way to move from gsl::not_null<T>?

Tags: c++, cpp-core-guidelines, guideline-support-library

The [Guidelines Support Library](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL) introduced `not_null<T>` who's purpose is to enforce an invariant on pointer-like types, advertently on smart pointers. However [it's a known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/issues/89) that `not_null<unique_ptr<T>>` doesn't work.

As far as I see the reason is that `unique_ptr<T>` is not copy-constructible and `not_null<T>` doesn't have a constructor that would move from its T. `not_null<T>` is not default-constructible either because it would break it's invariant. Even if we could construct `not_null<unique_ptr<T>>`, it would be impossible to meaningfully reach the `unique_ptr` inside because we couldn't copy `unique_ptr` and moving it would leave `not_null<T>` with a nullptr. It looks like a perfect trap.

I argued that we could legally move from a `not_null<T>` object in a specific context: just before it goes out of scope. In other words, moving from it should be the last access before destruction. That way the object with broken invariant wouldn't be observable to the rest of the program. (It would be observable for `not_null`'s own code only.)

In the following examples let's assume that we can move from `not_null<T>`.

```
not_null<unique_ptr<int>> f()
{
    return make_unique<int>(1);
}

void g(not_null<unique_ptr<int>> p)
{
    ...
}

void h()
{
    auto p = f();
    g(make_unique<int>(2));
}
```

1. Is my assumption correct that state of the `not_null<unique_ptr<int>>` returned from f() couldn't leak after moving from it (just for the example)?
2. Is my assumption correct that state of the `not_null<unique_ptr<int>>` passed to g() couldn't leak after moving from it (just for the example)?
3. Is it possible to allow this special kind of moving while prohibiting the common case of moving in C++14/17?

Comment: Regarding 3: see https://github.com/microsoft/GSL/pull/842, especially the comment from hsutter. For a general solution move construction in combination with `std::move` is a problem, compare `auto p=f(); auto q=std::move(p);` where after the move  `p` cannot hold any meaningful value that does not violate the class invariant "not null" (there is no valid default value to set `p` to).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1&2: Ignoring the fact that elision would render the question moot on any compiler worth using, yes. Also ignoring the fact that `unique_ptr` *cannot* "leak".

3: No.

This has been the subject of some debate on the ISO C++ proposals mailing list. The general concept is that of a "destructive move", where the act of moving from an object and destroying it are performed in the same call. But this would have to be a language feature; there is no way in C++14 to tell whether a move constructor/assignment is being called such that the given object is certainly about to be destroyed.

Comment: Copy elision is really tricky as it is "the only allowed form of optimization that can change the observable side-effects" (from cppreference.com). Thanks for mentioning it. By leaking I meant leaking information rather than memory, but your comment is relevant anyway. Finally, I didn't know about the debate but that was something I expected.